# How to pass RLMObject between thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, realm

I have a RLMArray of 10000 RLMObjects which can be sorted by their properties upon button touch events.

I want to kick back the sort process to a background thread via GCD and keep the UI fluid. Realm is not thread safe so as soon as i pass the updated RLMArray back to main thread, it crashes.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code, point out which line crashes, and provide details about the crash.

Comment: Why do you do the sort yourself, instead of getting them again from Realm with a different sortBy attribute?

Comment: There is still a small lag by refetching realm objects agin with a different sortBy attribute. For some record, we have over 50,000 RLMObjects.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's correct. Realm objects are not thread-safe. If you need to move them between threads, the easiest way is to give each object a primary key and then re-fetch the object on the new thread using its primary key (Using the `[RLMObject objectForPrimaryKey:]` method).

In this case, it might be best to perform your sort, and then use the results to build an `NSArray` of the objects' primary keys. You can then pass this array to the new thread, and then refetch the objects out of it as you need them.

Thankfully, refetching objects in Realm is lightning quick, so while this may seem rather inefficient, you shouldn't experience any non-trivial performance loss.